# Difference between clusters() and components() - R igraph

Tags: r, cluster-analysis, igraph

From the R igraph documentation, I see that I have a `components` and I have a `clusters` function, both of which are described as "Connected components of a graph" and link out to the same documentation (https://igraph.org/r/doc/). I tried them on my data, and I also get the same cluster membership results.

Are these two functions equivalent or is there a subtle difference I am missing? (I am a complete igraph newbie!)

Comment: They are identical. If you are using RStudio, click on F2 to see the function contents.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`clusters` is the older name of the function. It was at one point renamed to `components`, which is the standard term in graph theory. The old name was kept for compatibility.